# TableView content Height Changed after keyboard show

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a Scroll View, Table View, and textfield at the bottom which will trigger a keyboard show after clicked.
Table View is just a subview inside the Scroll view which to show some comments for that photos.

At the beginning, the tableView height shows correctly. However, after clicked any textField in the class, the tableView height changed. Anyone has solutions for this.

I have tested for the keyboard height. It will affect the additional height of the UITableView.
But I have no any ideas on how to keep the height the same as before the keyboard shows.

Please help.

Here is some codes,

```
//---when a TextField view begins editing---
-(BOOL) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textFieldView {  
        currentTextField = textFieldView;

        return YES;
}  

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *) textFieldView {  
    [textFieldView resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

//---when a TextField view is done editing---
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *) textFieldView {  
    currentTextField = nil;
}

//---when the keyboard appears---
-(void) keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *) notification {
    if (keyboardIsShown) return;

    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];

    //---obtain the size of the keyboard---
    NSValue *aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;

    //---resize the scroll view (with keyboard)---
    CGRect viewFrame = [v_comment_editor frame];
    viewFrame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
    v_comment_editor.frame = viewFrame;

    //---scroll to the current text field---
    CGRect textFieldRect = [currentTextField frame];
    [v_comment_editor scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:YES];

    keyboardIsShown = YES;
}

//---when the keyboard disappears---
-(void) keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *) notification {
    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];

    //---obtain the size of the keyboard---
    NSValue *aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;

    //---resize the scroll view back to the original size (without keyboard)---
    CGRect viewFrame = [v_comment_editor frame];
    viewFrame.size.height += keyboardSize.height;
    v_comment_editor.frame = viewFrame;

    keyboardIsShown = NO;
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    //---removes the notifications for keyboard---
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     removeObserver:self 
     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
     object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     removeObserver:self 
     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
     object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show does resize the views when the keyboard is shown. It looks like it is supposed to return to the correct size when keyboard is hidden again.

If you have trouble with one of the subviews, it is possible that it's autoresize masks are set up in a weird way.

The simplest way around it would be to have an instance variable in your handling class like:

```
CGRect tableframe;
```

and store the correct frame to it in the **keyboarddidshow** function, and restore the table to the original frame in ** keyboardDidHide** method.

Answer (score 0):

Might help to look into [UIScrollView's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) `contentOffset` and `contentInset` properties. Also it will help to understand the difference between the `bounds` of the scrollView and the `frame`.

I strongly advise creating a simple test project and experimenting with the above concepts. Having a thorough understanding will make your life much easier.

Note: be careful of translucent navigationBars and their affect on the above properties.

Answer (score 0):

For all of other people reference, in case you have this problem again.

The solution i used to go through this is to reset the size again in the keyboardDidHide, and code is as below:

```
CGRect frame = tbl_comment.frame;
    frame.size.height = 145;
    tbl_comment.frame = frame;
```